# Why am I getting "An error occured while processing your request"?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

[image: screenshot]

I am trying to use Azure AD B2C to log in through a third party on my app. I always keep getting the error shown in the image with no way of finding out what it is.

Keep in mind that my app is in development mode.

I tried changing the policies, making a new application, and even got a working sample online that gave me the same error. Can you provide any help?

Comment: Hi Husseinnd. What do you see in Azure AD B2C audit logs? https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/active-directory-b2c/view-audit-logs. Please add to your question more info about your app. This will make someone easier to help you. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try to activate App Insight with the Development mode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights

Comment: @greenmarker I checked the docs on Microsoft and the logs are useful if I need to debug AFTER a user logs in. My app wont reach the login page at the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're working on .Net Core which requires you to check both fields "ID tokens" and "Access Tokens" under your Azure App Registrations -> Authentication.